# Деформация 3D модели с помощью кривых Безье

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, mesh

Пишу программу, которая должна деформировать модель по опорным точкам.

Получилось написать следующий код, который создает полотно процедурно по 16 опорным точкам. Вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
//вычисляем полином Бершнейна третьей степени на основании четырех точек
XMFLOAT3 Bernstein(float u, XMFLOAT3 p1, XMFLOAT3 p2, XMFLOAT3 p3, XMFLOAT3 p4) {
    XMFLOAT3 a, b, c, d;

    a = pointTimes(pow(u, 3), p1);
    b = pointTimes(3 * pow(u, 2) * (1 - u), p2);
    c = pointTimes(3 * u * pow((1 - u), 2), p3);
    d = pointTimes(pow((1 - u), 3), p4);

    return pointAdd(pointAdd(a, b), pointAdd(c, d));
}

//тоже самое что и верхняя функция, только принимаем указатель на массив точек
XMFLOAT3 Bernstein(float u, XMFLOAT3 *p) {
    XMFLOAT3 a, b, c, d;

    a = pointTimes(pow(u, 3), p[0]);
    b = pointTimes(3 * pow(u, 2) * (1 - u), p[1]);
    c = pointTimes(3 * u * pow(1 - u, 2), p[2]);
    d = pointTimes(pow(1 - u, 3), p[3]);

    return pointAdd(pointAdd(a, b), pointAdd(c, d));
}

void CreateSurfaceByControlPoints(XMFLOAT3 points[], D3DTextureVertex **ppVertices) {
    const int step = 16;    //количество делений у полотна
                            //чем больше делений, тем глаже модель становится (создается больше вершин)

    const int max = (step * (step + 1) * 2);    //общее количество вершин у модели

    XMFLOAT3 temp[4];
    XMFLOAT3 *last = new XMFLOAT3[step + 1];

    //в массиве points, размером 16 точек,
    //у меня верхняя линия с индексами от 0 до 3, следющая от 4 до 7 и т.д.

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        temp[i] = points[(i + 1) * 4 - 1];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < step + 1; i++) {
        last[i] = Bernstein((float)i / (float)step, temp);
    }

    *ppVertices = new D3DTextureVertex[max];

    int c = 0; //счетчик текущей вершины

    for(int i = 1; i < step + 1; i++) {
        float py = (float)i / (float)step;
        float pyold = ((float)i - 1.0f) / (float)step;

        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            temp[j] = Bernstein(py, points[j * 4 + 0], points[j * 4 + 1], points[j * 4 + 2], points[j * 4 + 3]);
        }

        for(int j = 0; j <= step; j++) {
            float px = static_cast<float>(j) / (float)step;

            (*ppVertices)[c++] = D3DTextureVertex(last[j].x, last[j].y, last[j].z, pyold, px);

            last[j] = Bernstein(px, temp);

            (*ppVertices)[c++] = D3DTextureVertex(last[j].x, last[j].y, last[j].z, py, px);
        }
    }

    delete[] last;
}
```

Все вышесказанное работает отлично, но теперь задача усложнилась и мне нужно загружать произвольную модель (она тоже 2D, как и моя процедурная), добавлять опорные точки таким же образом и деформировать меш по такому же подобию.

Модель уже имеет свою геометрию и UV координаты.
Выглядит следующим образом:

[image: загруженный меш из .obj файла]
Главный вопрос - есть ли какая-нибудь формула, чтобы рассчитать позицию для каждого вертекса, основываясь на 8 кривых Безье (4 горизонтальных и 4 вертикальных), учитывая их первоначальную позицию? Как, например, в профессиональных программах Maya или Blender есть такие инструменты, как произвольно расставить опорные точки и делать с моделью любые деформации.

Comment: Попробуйте так: 1. *Найдите расстояние от вертекса до точки пересечения его нормали с поверхностью полотна*. 2. *Переместите вертекс вдоль нормали на величину, пропорциональную этому расстоянию*. Однако поверхность Безье для этого алгоритма должна быть замкнута вокруг модели. Либо убедитесь перед деформацией вертекса, что его нормаль пересекает участок этой поверхности в пределах границы «листа». В противном случае модель попросту «размажет» по этой поверхности.

Comment: @Arhad, спасибо за быстрый комментарий, можете поподробнее рассказать (или дать ссылки на материал) как найти нормаль вершины? Я так понимаю, мне нужно на основе боковых кривых создать плоскость и найти нормаль по отношению к ней, но сработает ли это, если у меня вершина итак находится на плоскости? Т.е. координата Z у всех вершин (включая контрольные точки) равна нулю. Можно ли, учитывая это, оптимизировать алгоритм без нахождения нормали и просто как-то рассчитать зависимость в двухмерном пространстве? Спасибо.

Comment: Как у вас описана модель, массивом вершин или контуром-сплайном Безье?

Comment: @Arhad, модель полотна описана массивом вершин, как и каждая из 8 кривых Безье.

Comment: Кто-нибудь может подсказать хотя бы по каким ключевым словам искать формулы для данного алгоритма?

Comment: Попробуйте просто подставить две координаты вершины модели в качестве коэффициентов *u* и *v* «листа».

Comment: `Кто-нибудь может подсказать` – уведомления из комментариев приходят только автору вопроса/ответа и ранее комментировавшим. Для запроса помощи можете обратиться в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52942/discussion-between-igor-0xe4-and-arhad).

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо за помощь!
Получилось решить проблему следующим образом:

```
//1378 и 861 - значения у меня рассчитаны, чтобы вся модель умещалась на экране
//у вас они могут быть другие или вообще по-другому считаться, главное, чтобы pz и px были в пределах [0.0f, 1.0f]

//в переменной points хранятся опорные точки
//в ppOutVertices хранится указатель на вершины, которые будем задавать
//в ppBaseVertices хранится массив вершин по-умолчанию, на основе которых формируем новый массив
//nVertices - количество вершин в моделе

void UpdateSurface(XMFLOAT3 points[], D3DTextureVertex **ppOutVertices, D3DTextureVertex **ppBaseVertices, UINT nVertices) {
    XMFLOAT3 tmp[4];

    *ppOutVertices = new D3DTextureVertex[nVertices];

    for(int i = 0; i < nVertices; i++) {
        float pz = (float)(*ppBaseVertices)[i].Pos.x / (1378.0f / 100.0f);

        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            tmp[j] = Bernstein(pz, points[j * 4 + 0], points[j * 4 + 1], points[j * 4 + 2], points[j * 4 + 3]);
        }

        float px = (float)(*ppBaseVertices)[i].Pos.z / (861.0f / 100.0f);
        XMFLOAT3 bern = XMFLOAT3(Bernstein(px, tmp));

        (*ppOutVertices)[i].Pos = XMFLOAT3(bern.x, 0.0f, bern.z);
    }
}
```